# Return related Guids instead of Ids in Django-Rest-Framework Serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that has the following:

```
class TeamInvite(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='invites_sent')
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='invites_received')
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team_invites')
    guid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)

class UserMetaData(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='usermetadata')
    guid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

I'm trying to obscure the serialization of my users by returning only the guid field in Django Rest Framework. Here was my first attempt, but it doesn't seem to work

```
class InviteListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.usermetadata.guid

class TeamInviteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lookup_field = 'guid'
    inviter = InviteListingField(read_only=True)
    invitee = InviteListingField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = TeamInvite
        fields = ('guid', 'inviter', 'invitee', 'team'
```

)

Problem 1: I only want this special serialization to apply to GET (detail) and List calls.

Problem 2: Am I distinguishing between inviter and invitee the right way? Because it seems that when I get into the to_representation method value is the same thing both times.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can provide a per-method serializer by overriding `get_serializer_class` on the ViewSet, something like this:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == 'retrieve':
        return CreateSerializer
    else:
        return super().get_serializer_class()
```

2) You can map serialiezr fields from sub-objects, something like this:

```
class TeamInviteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lookup_field = 'guid'
    inviter = UUIDField(read_only=True, source='inviter.guid')
    invitee = UUIDField(read_only=True, source='invitee.guid')
```